# Execute gradle task when its dependency is still running

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, e2e-testing, end-to-end

I have to run a jar file and exec npm tests on it, but using gradle tasks. I'm using `dependsOn` to run the `npm test` after the jar is running.

These are my gradle tasks:

```
task runServer1 (type: Exec) {
// Run the jar file
}

task runNpmTest (type: Exec, dependsOn: ':runServer1') {
// Run npm tests
}
```

The problem is that when I execute `gradle runNpmTest` gradle stops at `runServer1`, which makes sense, because the server is still running. But my NPM tests will never run.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work this way, since `runServer1` task is still running - it's a process. What you need is to run a server in background - so it won't block the main thread - and then run the tests. This probably should be done in a single task and configured via actions. Please have a look [here](https://github.com/marc0der/gradle-spawn-plugin) and [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1367) to catch some useful knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, based on your answer I found this plugin https://libraries.io/github/avast/docker-compose-gradle-plugin
and this solved pretty nice.